# Operators and valueOf with ES6 proxies (Firefox)

Tags: javascript, firefox, ecmascript-6

I run the following code:

```
var x = new Proxy({}, {
    get: function(target, name) {
        console.log(name);
        return target[name];
    }
});

var y = x + 5;
```

Why isn't `'valueOf'` printed in console (in Firefox 24)?

See http://jsfiddle.net/WFjvv/1/.

Comment: Is it just me, or does this work fine? I see on the HTML page `valueOf`, then `toString`, which is how I think it's supposed to work.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy yes, seems to be working properly in Firefox 26

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be fixed in Firefox 26.